# mod_wsgi-express set log level

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

**How to set the log level** in a wsgi application started with

```
mod_wsgi-express ./mywsgi.py
```

? This is the most simple setup. [Logging in python + mod_wsgi app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385915/logging-in-python-mod-wsgi-app) talks about config files, as does the [Quick Configuration Guide](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html?highlight=--log-level). The `mod_wsgi-express` command needs only the python wsgi file to operate.

Using the `--log-level` flag, as mentioned in [the release notes](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/release-notes/version-4.4.10.html)

```
mod_wsgi-express --log-level info ./mywsgi.py
```

did not show `logging.info` messages. Neither did the `--debug-mode` flag [mentioned by @GrahamDumpleton](http://file:///home/uni/Downloads/using-modwsgi-express-as-development.html).

#### Solved (see below), but still: minimal example

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    logging.warning('warning log message')
    logging.info('info log message')

    output = "hello world"

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also (see example above) need to enable `INFO` (f.ex.) level logging in the wsgi program. For example via the line

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
```

If you then start with `--log-level info`, you see `logging.info` output in the `error_log`.